# Python yagmail authentication configuration

Tags: python-3.x, yagmail

I'm trying to setup yagmail with an external .yagmail file with credentials but when I run the code it returns

```
YagInvalidEmailAddress: Emailaddress "yagmail.register('my.username@gmail.com', 'my.password')" is not valid according to RFC 2822 standards
```

the .yagmail file is like this

```
yagmail.register('my.username@gmail.com', 'my.password')
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should run the following once in python, which will store the registration in the backend (yagmail.register is just a wrapper around keyring lib functionality):

```
import yagmail

yagmail.register(email, pwd)
```

After this, you can just use the following in your script to start using yagmail:

```
yag = yagmail.SMTP(email)
yag.send()
```

If you want to omit the email as well, you can write your gmail address in the .yagmail file, which should reside in you $HOME directory.

Then, you could just use:

```
yag = yagmail.SMTP()
yag.send()
```

On some systems (CentOS for me), you also need to `pip install keyrings.alt` and `import keyrings` in your registration script.